# React: myRef.current and myRef.current.offsetHeight are different

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

### What I wanna do:

I wanna pass my children header wrapper header to my parent in order to do styling in parent.js

### what I am doing:

I am trying to get the myRef.current.offsetHeight using document.querySelector('#header_wrapper');. However, I am having some issues getting the correct height of my wrapper. I logged the myRef.current and myRef.current.offsetHeigh on my browser, and they show different offset height.

and my parent is rendering {children}.

### This is my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
      myRef.current = document.querySelector('#header_wrapper');
      console.log('my ref: ', myRef);
      console.log('my ref height 2', myRef.current.offsetHeight);
  }, []);
```

[image: element.current]

[image: element.current.offsetHeight]

### Problems

myRef.current and myRef.current.offsetHeight shows different offsetHeight. What should I do to correct it ?

Comment: Is the `'#header_wrapper'` element *outside* this component? Have you added any "offsetHeight" logging on that element directly in order to correlate which value here is correct? Can you attach the ref to the element directly instead of querying the DOM for it? Console logs are a bit asynchronous so once the ref is pointing to a DOMNode and it is scrolled I believe it is possible for the ref value to be mutated between logs.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese .For the first question: yes, it is outside my component, do you think this cause issue? I need to use get the header wrapper height from my children component, so then I can use the height to do some styling on my parent wrapper. Basically, I wanna pass the height from my children wrapper to its parent wrapper. I tried using useRef, but it shows me the same error.

Comment: And also, it shows me the correct height after I resize the screen.

Comment: So the parent component is trying to get some information from the child component? Perhaps it would be clearer to us if you provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Seems you just need to pass a ref or callback to the child.